# Dynamic array initialization

Tags: c++

I want to make a dynamic array of foo, with the number of items being x. Arguments y and z are to be passed to the constructor of the item foo. I was hoping to do something similar to:

```
Foo* bar = new Foo(y, z)[x];
```

However that produced the following compiler error:

```
 error: expected `;' before '[' token
```

So after speaking with an experienced friend, he gave me this, which he admitted was a lazy way of doing it, but it works. I was wondering, is there a better/proper way?

```
Foo* bar = (Foo*) new int[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    bar[i] = Foo(y, z);
}
```

Comment: You and your friend should get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get a good base of understanding. I mean that second code block is just wrong, why allocate `int` and then cast to `foo`? That's almost certainly undefined behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"I want to make a dynamic array" So use a `std::vector`, it exists for a reason.

```
std::vector<foo> bar(x, foo(y, z));
```

This creates a dynamic array with `x` elements initialized to `foo(y, z)`.

---

The above makes *copies* of the second parameter, `x` times. If you want to *generate* values for the `vector`, use `generate_n`:

```
std::vector<double> weights;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(weights), x, ...);
```

You replace `...` with a function or functor to call, that returns a value. Generally you make a functor:

```
struct generate_weight
{
    double operator()() const
    {
        return random(1e-3);
    }
};
```

Giving:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(weights), x, generate_weight());
```

If your compiler supports C++0x, you can take advantage of lambda's. These do the same thing, except they keep the code concise and localized:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(weights), x,
                [](){ return random(1e-3); } );
```

Comment: Whilst this works fine, in this example it returns the same number for all items in the array:  

std::vector<double> weights(x, random(1e-3));

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed it does, it initializes it to `x` copies of `foo(y, z)`. Your question said nothing about anything else; ask real questions to get real answers. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was just looking to see if that was the expected behavior, having no experience with STL before this. I used the random(1e-3) as an example.
Thanks for the extended answer.

Comment: @Daniel: No problem. Programming C++ without using the standard library is...unwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize each element to the same value, then do as GMan suggested above:

```
std::vector<foo> bar(x, foo(y, z));
```

You will have a vector of X elements, each with the same foo(y,z);

If you want a unique value for each of the foos you will need to initialize it in a loop.  one simple example of how is:

```
std::vector<foo> bar;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        // initialize X foos with different values for each foo.
        bar.push_back(foo(i, random(i)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the only initializer you can use in the array new-expressions is `()`. So, these are you only options if you want to use new-expression

```
foo *bar = new foo[x];   // 1. no initializer
foo *bar = new foo[x](); // 2. `()` initializer
```

Depending on how `foo` is defined, these two might behave identically or differently.

Secondly, since you can't pass the constructor arguments `(y,z)` in new-expression, you have to default-construct your array (as shown above) and then use assignment to give your array elements specific values. For this your `foo` has to be default-constructible and copy-assignable. The code will look pretty much like what your "experienced friend" suggested, but with proper types (instead of `int`). What you have now is useless (where did that `int` come from?). Most likely you misunderstood your experienced friend. This is how it is supposed to look

```
foo *bar = new foo[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  bar[i] = foo(y,z);
```

Thirdly, in your specific case `std::vector` will do the same thing in a much more elegant way.

Comment: That was my original code, however I would have to make a constructor to handle no arguments (as you said, 'default constructible'?) when using "foo *bar = new foo[x];". And then re-init them all as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in not using std at least do it properly. This is not safe and has BIG alignment issues.

```
size_t x = 10;
foo * bar= static_cast<foo*> (::operator new ( sizeof(foo)* x));
for (size_t i=0; i<x; ++i)
{
    new (&bar[i]) foo (1,1); 
}

::operator delete (bar);
```

Comment: There's no alignment issues here, `operator new` returns a maximally aligned block of memory.

Comment: @GMan - I'm afraid not this will ignore alignment of foo.

Comment: Again, there are no alignment issues. §3.7.3.1/2: "...The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type and then used to access the object or array in the storage allocated..."